# Determine roots of a polynomial with variable exponent

Tags: polynomials, roots

I need to know the nature of the roots of the equation $$ x(x+a)^b -1 = 0 $$ when changing a and b, where $ a,b  $ are natural numbers, I've looked around on the web but I was unable to find how to do it.

Comment: What do you mean by "nature"?

Comment: @G.Sassatelli like if it is real or complex

Comment: there is at least one real root, but probably not every root is real for big $b$

Comment: so is there any way to know the number of real solutions of the equations?

Comment: i would conjecture that there are exactly 2 real roots for odd $b$ and 1 real root for even $b$, but i don't know how to prove it, maybe using derivatives of that polynomials...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P_{a,b}=x(x+a)^b-1$.

If $a=0$ the problem is easily solved. So let $a\neq 0$.

$P'_{a,b}(x)=(x+a)^b+bx(x+a)^{b-1}=(x+a)^{b-1}((1+b)x+a)$

So, now we must make a couple of cases:

- if $b$ is odd, then $P'_{a,b}(x)>0\Longleftrightarrow x>-\frac{a}{1+b}\ $ so $P_{a,b}$ has at most $2$ real roots, depending on the sign of the global minimum $P_{a,b}\left(-\frac{a}{1+b}\right)=-\frac{a^{b+1}b^b}{(1+b)^{b+1}}-1<0$

  So $P_{a,b}$ has exactly $2$ real roots if $b$ is odd.
- if $b$ is even, then $P'_{a,b}(x)>0\Longleftrightarrow x<-a\vee x>-\frac{a}{1+b}$; this tells us that $P_{a,b}$ has a local maximum in $x=-a$ and a local minimum in $x=-\frac{a}{1+b}$. Notice, though, that $P_{a,b}(-a)<0$. So there can be only one real root.

Comment: Yes, @JackD'Aurizio, I spent the last two minutes debunking my on mistakes.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Now it works. I had left too many cases bcause I did not calculate the minimum. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way, without the calculus, but still giving insight.

$x(x+a)^b-1$ is a polynomial with exactly $1$ sign change, so by Descartes' rule of signs, there is always exactly one positive root which clearly is in $(0, 1)$.

Let us now seek negative roots. With $y =x+a$, the polynomial is $(y-a)y^b-1 = y^{b+1}-ay^b-1$, so with only one sign change, we know there are no roots for $x \in (-a, 0)$.

Further setting $y \to -z$, we get $(-1)^{b+1}(z^{b+1}+az^b)-1$, which has no sign change if $b$ is even, and exactly $1$ sign change if $b$ is odd.

Putting it together, we have for even $b$ exactly one real root in $(0, 1)$ and for odd $b$, one root in $(0, 1)$ and another $< -a$.

Comment: It is nice, but doesn't the Descartes' rule of signs just provide an upper bound for the number of real roots? We still need a little argument of calculus (limits at infinity, for instance) to have a lower bound, too.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Descartes rule provides more than an upper bound.  It says the number of roots can only be different from the bound by an even number.  So if you have an upper bound of $1$, it is in fact exactly the number of roots.  In this problem, nothing else is needed, so no calculus.

Comment: Fine, thanks. $\phantom{}$

Comment: For reference... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descartes'_rule_of_signs

Answer (score 1):

If $a=0$, there are trivially one or two real roots, depending on $b$ being even/odd.

Assume now that $a>0$ and $b$ is odd. $f(x)=x(x+a)^b$ has just two real roots, $x=0$ and $x=-a$. By computing $f'(x)$, it is easy to check that $f(x)$ has an absolute minimum $\xi\in(-a,0)$, $f(\xi)<0$, $f(x)$ is decreasing over $(-\infty,\xi)$ and increasing over $(\xi,+\infty)$, so $f(x)=1$ has just two real roots, one root close to zero and the other one close to $-a-1$.

In the same way we may check that if $a>0$ and $b$ is even, $f(x)=x(x+a)^b$ is non-positive over $\mathbb{R}^-$ and increasing over $\mathbb{R}^+$, so $f(x)=1$ in just one point, close to zero.

Answer (score 0):

There is a new special and multivalued function called Lambert-Tsallis, where you can find details about at "Physica A: Statistical Mechanics and its Applications 525, 164-170", or to get in contact with a friend and coworker R. V. Ramos.
The solution to your problem is given by

$x= \frac{a}{b}\cdot W_q( \frac{b}{a^{1+b}} )$ with $q= \frac{b-1}{b}$.
For the case where a and b are naturals, this solution:

1. It will have $b+1$ solution.
2. When $b$ is even, there is only one positive solution the other are complex (and is conjugate)
3. When $b$ is odd, there will be two real solution with oposite signals and the others will appear in complex conjugated pairs.

One interesting solution arises when $a=b=1$ because $x$ will value  the negative of both golden numbers, because $W_0(1)$.